# Different image size on Safari iOS Mobile

Tags: html, ios, css, mobile, safari

I have a problem with my website on iOS mobile devices - the image height isn't at is should be (look at the images).

Here is the [website](http://riccardofiverr.000webhostapp.com/files/home.html) if you want to look

The image has these attributes:

```
height: auto;
max-height: 1000px;
width: 100%;
max-width: 100%
```

[behavior on normal broswer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRtvX.jpg)

[behavior on safari ios][3]

[image]
[image]